# Creating PDF file gives error (Adobe Acrobat: It was sent as an email attachment and not correctly decoded!)

Tags: php

I want to create a CV with (.pdf) format using below code,

```
$data = "<P>This is my CV</P>";
$file = "cv.pdf";
$openedFile = fopen($file, "w");
fwrite($openedFile, $data);
fclose($openedFile);
$fileOpen = fopen($file, 'r');
$content = fread($fileOpen, filesize($file));
$fsize = filesize($file); 
$ftype = filetype($file);
fclose($fileOpen);
unlink($file);  // i don't want to store the file so i remove it
header("Content-length: $fsize");
header("Content-type: $ftype");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
echo $data;
exit;
```

It will create it for me and will show a download dialog box to download the file, after downloading i can not open the file it gives me the error

> Error Adobe Acrobat: It was sent as an email attachment and not
>   correctly decoded!

But it is working for (.doc) file types.

Please help me!

Comment: Do all PDFs do this, or just this one?

Comment: You can't just write text to a file and call it a PDF.  PDFs are a specific format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = "<P>This is my CV</P>";
$file = "cv.pdf";
$openedFile = fopen($file, "w");
fwrite($openedFile, $data);
fclose($openedFile);
```

This code does **not** make a PDF file.  It just makes a text (`.txt`) file and *names* it `.pdf`.  That doesn't magically make it into a PDF.  PDFs are a special (binary) format (they have special headers and the "text" is stored in a special way), so Adobe Reader has no idea what to do with the file you gave it.

In order to make a PDF file in PHP, you need to use a special library, like dompdf (https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf).

---

It "works" for `.doc` files, but not for the reason you think.  `.doc` files are also a binary format.  The thing is, Microsoft Word can also open `.txt` files (which is what you are really making, just renaming it), so it just reads the `.doc` file as a `.txt` file.  It just "worked" by coincidence.

To make "real" `.doc` files, you also need a special library, like PHPWord (http://phpword.codeplex.com/documentation).

---

P.S. There are still other things wrong with this code, but this is the most important.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, if you have time so please tell me that what else me be wrong with my code???

Comment: @SamimNaimy: The `Content-type` header wants a MIME Type, `filetype($file)` does not return you that.  You want `mime_content_type($file)`.  Since you are making a PDF, you can just hardcode `application/pdf`. Also, if you are not storing the file, there's no reason to use a file on your hard drive only to delete it later.  To get the file size you can just use `strlen($data)`.

Comment: Thank you so much dear Rocket Hazmat, may ALLAH bless u, u solved my problem

Comment: Glad I could help! :-D

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying is impossible .

Make use of PDF libraries like [`TCPDF`](http://www.tcpdf.org/), [`DOMPDF`](https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) to convert the textual content to PDF.

### Illustration using FPDF

Here's a link of demonstration using [`FPDF`](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1414-how-to-generate-a-pdf-with-php/)